# date/time compare and then perform an action

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

when one of my staff travel, they are entitled to travel comptime. My access vba already compares the date/time of departure to date/time of arrival at work site. How can I subtract the work hours from the flight time? to make matters even crazier, I have to account for time zones.

here the example I am working with (because if I an get this, the rest will fall into line).
staff departs Manila Philippines (UTC 8) on 3/7/22 at 00:15, arrives Washington DC (UTC -5) 3/7/22 at 16:10. total flight time is 1735 minutes (28 hours 55 minutes). Since the flight was over the workday, I need to subtract 480 minutes from the flight time.

How can I code this to date/time compare the workday and the flight date/time depart and date/time arrive to subtract out the 480 minutes of the workday?

I know the code i have attached may have "air code", but I am not a programmer by trade, just a guy trying to help his staff earn the most comptime they can.

```
depflt = MsgBox("Was day of departure a workday?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

    If depflt = vbYes Then
        If DTDeptdy < Strworkday Then
            Me.TxtholdtimeDiff = DateRound(DTDeptdy - Strworkday, 0, 15, 0)
            Me.TxtholdtimeDiff = Format(Me.TxtholdtimeDiff, "h") * 60 + Format(Me.TxtholdtimeDiff, "n")
            pda = Me.TxtholdtimeDiff
            'Me.TxtHoldTrvAirport = DateRound(arvairport - gotoairport, 0, 15, 0)
            'Me.TxtHoldTrvAirport = Format(Me.TxtHoldTrvAirport, "h") * 60 + Format(Me.TxtHoldTrvAirport, "n")
            Trvdiff = Me.TxtHoldTrvAirport
            
        Else
            If DTDeptdy > Strworkday And DTDeptdy < Endworkday Then
                pda = 0
            Else
                If DTDeptdy > Endworkday Then
                    Me.TxtholdtimeDiff = DateRound(DTDeptdy - Endworkday, 0, 15, 0)
                    Me.TxtholdtimeDiff = Format(Me.TxtholdtimeDiff, "h") * 60 + Format(Me.TxtholdtimeDiff, "n")
                    pda = Me.TxtholdtimeDiff
                    Me.TxtHoldTrvAirport = DateRound(arvairport - gotoairport, 0, 15, 0)
                    Me.TxtHoldTrvAirport = Format(Me.TxtHoldTrvAirport, "h") * 60 + Format(Me.TxtHoldTrvAirport, "n")
                    Trvdiff = Me.TxtHoldTrvAirport
                        If pda >= 180 Then
                            pda = 180
                        End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
Else
    Me.TxtHoldTrvAirport = DateRound(arvairport - gotoairport, 0, 15, 0)
    Me.TxtHoldTrvAirport = Format(Me.TxtHoldTrvAirport, "h") * 60 + Format(Me.TxtHoldTrvAirport, "n")
    Trvdiff = Me.TxtHoldTrvAirport
    pda = 180
End If
    
'sets variable to arrival date/time of flight
DTArvtdy = DateValue(Me.txtDateArvTDY) + TimeValue(Me.txtTimeFltArv)

    If txtDateArvTDY = txtDateDepTDY And DTArvtdy < Strworkday Or DTArvtdy > endoworkday Then
         arvtime = Me.txtArvAllowance * 60
    Else
         arvtime = 0
    End If
    
' determine the number of hours between date depart tdy and date arrive tdy
Me!txtHoldTime = DateRound(DTArvtdy - DTDeptdy, 0, 15, 0)
Me!txtHoldTime = Format(Me.txtHoldTime, "h") * 60 + Format(Me.txtHoldTime, "n")

' determine time diff between date arrived tdy and date depart tdy
TimeDiff = DateDiff("d", DTDeptdy, DTArvtdy)
TimeDiff = TimeDiff * 24 * 60

' determine time zone value if TimeDiff >=1
If TimeDiff <> 1 Then
tzvalue = TxtDutyStationUTC.Value - TxtTDYLocUTC.Value
    
    If tzvalue >= 1 Then
        tzvalue = tzvalue * 60
    Else
        tzvalue = -tzvalue * 60
    End If
End If
'sums the total time span
totmindep = arvtime + pda + tzvalue + Me.txtHoldTime + Trvdiff + TimeDiff + pdaDep

    If totmindep < 0 Then
        totmindep = 0
    Else
        totmindep = totmindep - workdaymin
    End If

'determines the actually allowable travel comptime.
'totalCTDep = Format(totmindep \ 60, "0") & ":" & Format(totmindep Mod 60, "00")

' sets the textbox to the total allowable travel time
' txtCTHADOD.SetFocus
' txtCTHADOD.Text = totalCTDep

' holds the total time on the outward leg of the journey for use later in the program
mytempvar = totmindep

' used to store total CompTime hours earned departing on TDY
Me.TxtHoldHoursDep = mytempvar / 60
```

Comment: What is "a workday" between different (and in-between) timezones?

Comment: Good question and I wish I had an equally good answer...I don't. So for my purposes, I need to check if the time the flight departed and the time the flight arrived (regardless of timezones) is equal to or greater than the start and end of the workday.  So as an example (basic) I travel 3/2/22 flight departs at 8:00am, and flight arrives 3/2/22 at 5:pm. my work day is between 8am and 5pm. in this scenario, I would earn no comptime.

Comment: Scenario 2: what if my flight leaves 3/2/22 at 5pm and arrives 3/3/22 at 5pm. under my current code, I would get 24 hours of comptime. What I need to do is subtract 8 hours as 3/3/22 is a workday. My comptime should be 16 hours. I can do the math in my head, but i need to do the math in code.

Comment: Yes, but strict rules will be needed to work out a solution.

Comment: here is how I solved my issue:                                                                                                   ' determine time diff between date arrived tdy and date depart tdy
TimeDiff = DateDiff("d", DTDeptdy, DTArvtdy)
TimeDiff = TimeDiff * 24 * 60
    If depflt = vbYes And TimeDiff = 1 Then
        noCTforworkday = -480
    End If

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to check if the dates are more than 24 hours apart:

```
// determine time diff between date arrived tdy and date depart tdy
TimeDiff = DateDiff("d", DTDeptdy, DTArvtdy)
TimeDiff = TimeDiff * 24 * 60
    If depflt = vbYes And TimeDiff = 1 Then
        noCTforworkday = -480
    End If
```

Comment: You cannot obtain a time difference from a difference in _calendar_ dates, as the time can be anything on both dates - not to mention, that the dates most likely are of different timezones.